# order list using sortable with id shown in each item using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jquery Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery_ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
            
            
            <li id="1" class="ui-state-default" >first - </li>
            <li id="2" class="ui-state-default" >second - </li>
            <li id="3" class="ui-state-default" >third - </li>
            <li id="4" class="ui-state-default" >fourth - </li>
            <li id="5" class="ui-state-default" >fifth - </li>
                                          
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
$('#sortable').sortable({
 //to prevent items from moving around when draging
 containment: "parent",
start : function(event, ui) {
// get the initial position(index) of item
var start_pos = ui.item.attr('id');
ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);

       },
       
update : function(event, ui) {
var index = ui.item.index();
var start_pos=ui.item.attr('id');

 //update the html of the moved item to the current index
 $('#sortable li:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').appendTo(index);

 if (start_pos < index) {
 
 //update the items before the re-ordered item
 for(var i=index; i > 0; i--){
 $('#sortable li:nth-child(' + i + ')').appendTo(i - 1);
 alert("start position = "+start_pos);
 alert("moved to position: "+index);
                         }
}
 else {
 
 //update the items after the re-ordered item
  for(var i=index+2;i <= $("#sortable li").length; i++){
  $('#sortable li:nth-child(' + i + ')').appendTo(i-1);
  
                }
            }
        },
  axis : 'y'
            });
        });
```

I want the program to sort the items while displaying the id next to each item.
For example, if item (fourth) is moved to item (first) the id next to fourth will be 1 and the id next to first will be 4. What error is in my code that is not displaying the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jPp8/2/) from your code. After running it I observed the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
```

The reason was the following line:

```
$('#sortable li:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').appendTo(index);
```

The code was failing because you are trying to append an HTML element to the variable index (which is numeric).

I've modified the update function as follows:

```
update: function (event, ui) {
    var index = ui.item.index();
    var start_pos = ui.item.attr('id');

    // Iterate over all <li> elements
    $.each($('#sortable li'), function (idx, item) {
        // Extract the text (e.g. 'first')
        var substringIndex = $(item).html().indexOf(' -') + 1;
        var html = $(item).html().substring(0, substringIndex);
        // Set the new index depending on position in list
        $(item).attr('id', (idx + 1));
        // Update the text on the <li> element
        $(item).html(html + ' - ' + (idx + 1));
    });
},
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6jPp8/1/) for a working Fiddle

Comment: thanks a lot its working now.but i dont understand  var substringIndex = $(item).html().indexOf(' -') + 1; if you can explain to me what does it mean

Comment: $(item).html() returns the text of the <li> e.g. "first -". using the indexOf() function on that returns the position in the string that the characters " -" appear

Comment: what if i want the ID to be changed and not the value.meaning: first:3,second:2,third:1